# Bundel.getString("") at onActivityResult() gives null value

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am working on android application in which i am passing data back from Activity 2 to Activity 1. I am passing it through intent. The problem is that in Activity 1, it is showing value in bundle, but when i am using `bundle.getString("");`, it is showing me null value. In debugging i am getting on bundle `Bundle[{list_size=3}]`. My code is given below, please help me out here.

Activity 1:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==105){
            TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
// It showing value at MBuddle, but at MBuddle it is showing null.
            Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
            String MMessage = MBuddle .getString("list_size");
            txtCounter.setText(MMessage);
        }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 105;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("list_size", fListContacts.size());
        setResult(REQUEST_CONTACTS, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use getIntent().. change your  code like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

to

```
Intent intent = geIntent();
```

Activity1

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==105){
        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
        // It showing value at MBuddle, but at MBuddle it is showing null.
        Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
        String MMessage = MBuddle .getString("list_size");
        txtCounter.setText(MMessage);
    }
}
```

Activity2

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 105;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("list_size", fListContacts.size());
    setResult(REQUEST_CONTACTS, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer here, but still it is not working. Can you please give me little bit more code snippet and hint here, it will be very useful to me.

Comment: thanks for your answer dear. But still it is not working. It is giving me the same null value here.

Comment: Please help me out here.

Comment: Can you post your error message here..and xml related to Activity1

Comment: Actually there is no error here. It is just showing null value at MBuddle.getString("list_size"); and the xml is just normal TEXTVIEW which is showing data. Please help me out here

Comment: without sharing your code i will not help.. some where it has problem...show your full code ans logs then only i will tell you the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)       

 if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT);
                }}
}
```

===============

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.putExtra(KEY, data);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

RESULT_OK can be a int value

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change your Activity 1, as given below. It may be because `fListContacts.size()` returns an `int` value :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==105){
        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
        Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
        String MMessage = String.valueOf(MBuddle.getInt("list_size"));
        txtCounter.setText(MMessage);
    }
}
```

and in Activity 2
change `new Intent()` to `getIntent()`